# Meaning of "be on" and "break"?

Tags: vocabulary, phrases

In one episode of the "How I met your mother" series, Ted is talking about his possible future wife (Robin). Here's the script:

> Ted: I just met a perfect woman! She was like this:( He starts to talk about Robin, how they like each other, and how they have a lot in common.)
>
> Marshall: Oh, it is on!
>
> It is on till the break of dawn (with robot motion).
>
> And then there was laughing sound and Ted also laughed.
>
> Lily: But wait. It's only the break of 10:30. What happened?
>
> Scenes back to what happened between Ted and Robin and how they had to leave each other)

I'm not a native speaker, but I think **"be on"** means something is going to start. Am I right? In this case, what is going to start, and does it have a sexual meaning?

And what does **"break"** in **"break of 10:30"** mean? Does it mean "about 10:30," or is Lily just joking about **"the break of dawn"** that Marshal said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line "on till the break of dawn" references the lyrics from *Rapper's paradise*:

> Well it's on and on and on, on and on
> The beat don't stop until the break of dawn

It probably has some sexual innuendo. The robot motion is an early '80s dance craze.

The "break of 10:30" is a deliberate mistake for comic reasons.  The idiom "the break of dawn" means the moment of dawn.  You don't say "The break of 10:30" unless you are joking.

Answer (score 1):

Hi so i think this is a sexual innuendo joke as in Ted and Marshall laughing that they would be lasting until the break of dawn and instead lily chides them that they would only last until 10:30.