What does "chicken and corn." mean?
In Deadpool & Wolverine (2024), Team is ready to face Cassandra:

Laura: Let's fu_king go.
Deadpool: Let's f_cking go!
Blade: It's on like chicken and corn.

what does "chicken and corn." mean ?

related https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/345454/meaning-of-be-on-and-break

"It's on" means the event (fight, etc) is going to happen now.
Then people like to complete the simile with a rhyme.  "Corn" rhymes with "on".  Also "Corn" (ie maize) is a common vegetable to eat with chicken, and chicken are often fed corn by the farmer.
It really doesn't have much meaning beyond that.  The internet finds lots of other possibilities, "... like the Wrath of Khan" or "... like queen takes pawn". See https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/b0tpa/ask_reddit_complete_the_following_sentence_its_on/  There's no real currency to any of these, and part of the show is the speaker inventing a new expression each time.
It references an early rap song which had the line "it's on till the break of dawn" Meaning of "be on" and "break"?

'Corn' rhymes with 'orn' (not a word), doesn't it? And that yellow stuff is 'sweetcorn' where I am. Clearly I am in neither the age- or geographically-related demographic for this film.

What is it with chicken? I had a colleague, who after mentioning a success, used to chant 'Winner winner, chicken dinner!'.

You're missing the image of chicken eating corn. Blade means he's going to fight like a flock of chicken fed corn.

@MichaelHarvey, until relatively recently, chicken was an expensive meat and a chicken dinner would be a celebration of a success. It is only with modern factory farming (a result of vent sexing in the 1930s) did chicken prices drop

@JamesK - Thanks (?) for making me find this: Vent sexing is a more delicate way of saying you’re checking the reproductive organs of the chick. This is done by carefully holding a chick upside down and squeezing it so that it empties its body of fecal matter. From there, light pressure is applied around the chick’s cloaca so that the vent area turns outward. A trained chicken sexer will be able to identify a slight bump that signifies that the chick is male. So now I know.

@JamesK - no more KFC for me!

@JamesK - and if the chick is male, it is killed using argon gas.

If it's lucky it gets the argon (or CO2), otherwise it's fed into a macerator: see chick culling on WP if you have a strong stomach.

@StuartF - Full disclosure: I'm a vegetarian.
